# How to get products by stock qty?

Tags: product, filter

I have the following code:

```
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$category =new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($cid);

if ($status == "2") {
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
    $products->load();
}

if ($status == "1") {
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $products->load();  
}
```

I want to add a filter of stock qty to filter the products, I tried:

```
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    **->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0));**
```

But not succuessful, any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to create a join with the *cataloginventory/stock_item* table to get the stock qty for a product, you could use:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->joinField('qty',
         'cataloginventory/stock_item',
         'qty',
         'product_id=entity_id',
         '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
         'left'
     )->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 0));
```

Comment: what the meaning of this row '{{table}}.stock_id=1' ?

Comment: In short it means you are loading the qty from the default stock item. {{table}} in this context translates to the cataloginventory_stock_item table and stock_id = 1 indicates that this is the default stock item.

Comment: I'm doing `$coll = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')` and using your join field and `addAttributeToFilter`. The collection is loading just fine. But the filter is not working: `->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))`. Looking at `$coll->getSelect()`, there is no reference to `qty` in the `WHERE` clause. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi @vladimir How to pass above code in soap apis

Answer (score 6):

ONE WAY:

```
$stockIds = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addQtyFilter('=', 30) //can be ->addQtyFilter('>=', 30), depending on requirement
    ->getAllIds();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($stockIds)
    ->setPageSize(10);
```

SECOND WAY:

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
)
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('eq' => 30));
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'FIRST WAY' in @TBI Infotech's answer wont work, as the `->getAllIds()` method returns the stock id, not the product ID.  Instead you need to add this;

```
$stockIds = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
->getCollection()
->addQtyFilter('>=', 30); 
//->getAllIds();

foreach($stockIds as $stock) {
   $idarray[] = $stock->getProductId();
}

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addIdFilter($idarray)
->setPageSize(10);
```

Comment: This logic is the very clear, simple, with no magic.

I wonder how efficient/slow/fast is `$stock->getProductId()`?

Answer (score 2):

Most elegant way:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```

Answer (score 1):

Late arriving answer, had a need to do some work on this code though, so here you go. It only takes a few joins, works for configurable and simple products, haven't tested against bundles.

```
$product_collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array(
            'css1' => $products->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')
        ),
        'e.entity_id = css1.product_id and css1.stock_id =1 AND css1.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
        ''
    )->joinLeft(
        array(
            'cpsl' => $products->getTable('catalog/product_super_link')
        ),
        'cpsl.parent_id = e.entity_id',
        ''
    )->joinLeft(
        array(
            'css2' => $products->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')
        ),
        'css2.product_id = cpsl.product_id and css1.stock_id =1 AND css1.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
        ''
    )->joinLeft(
        array(
            'cpei' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'
        ),
        "cpei.entity_id = cpsl.product_id AND cpei.entity_type_id = $entity_type_id and cpei.attribute_id = $attribute_id AND (cpei.value IS NULL OR cpei.value = " . Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED . ")",
        ''
    )->group(
        'e.entity_id'
    )->columns(
        array(
            'qty' => new Zend_Db_Expr ("IF(`e`.`type_id` = 'simple', `css1`.qty, sum(css2.qty))")
        )
    )->having(
        'qty > 0'
);
```

Comment: I'm having a slow day today...
Is it
$products = Mage::getModel('core/resource');
and 
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection();