# Magento 1.9 Collection returning Qty Null

Tags: magento-1.9

im using this code to get all product collections and Qty but is returning null

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        if(!empty($products)) {
            foreach($products as $product) {
                $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products);
                $qty = $stock->getQty();
                var_dump($qty);
            }
        }
```

this code return "NULL"

Comment: check you two link -- 1) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106455/get-product-stock-quantity-in-magento 2)https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33738/how-to-get-products-by-stock-qty

Comment: i try this, but return null too

Comment: Guess it is a typo ... `loadByProduct($products)` should be `loadByProduct($product)` w/o "s" ;) Otherwise see below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this ... add

```
$products
    ...
    ->setFlag('require_stock_items', true);
```

More info here [Get product stock quantity in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106455/get-product-stock-quantity-in-magento/209510#209510)